# What type should I use for an unknown string enum argument?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to type an unknown string enum argument with no success, as a string enum is not assignable to a param of type string. Here is my use case:

```js
const func = (
  enumerator: Record<number, string>,
  callback: (value: string) => string,
) => Object.values(enumerator).map(callback);

enum Category {
  HAZARDOUS = "HAZARDOUS",
  REGULAR = "REGULAR",
}

enum OtherCategory {
  DRY = "DRY",
  REEFER = "REEFER",
}

func(Category, (value: Category) => t(value));
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
func(OtherCategory, (value: OtherCategory) => t(value));
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
Argument of type '(value: Category) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string) => string'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Category'.
```

What should I use to type the `enumerator` and `value` arguments?

Comment: Bad spelling of Category 

Comment: Why callback typed as `callback: (value: string) => string`? Is it supposed to get only `Catergory`?

Comment: It's not clear if you are trying to create a function to work with any string enum, or just with this one. In the first case, you probably need a generic, and in the second one, there's no need to accept it as an argument

Comment: Edited taking in account your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need templates to do this with IntelliSense. We can describe enum as `Record<string, string | number>`. Try this:

```
enum Catergory {
  HAZARDOUS = "HAZARDOUS",
  REGULAR = "REGULAR",
}

const func = <T extends Record<string, number | string>>(enumerator: T, callback: (value: T[keyof T]) => string | number) => Object.values(enumerator).map((value) => callback(value as T[keyof T]));
func(Catergory, (value) => "sfdsf");
```

[Working demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgF2AJwOYHtkE8oG8BQUUAEgIIBapASgCIDyAqgMpQC8UARGZbY0xwBpCUKgFEA4gwAy1NpzGSZVQfgC++fAGN0IAM4IoAMzAhNcgDwAVKMAAeSEABNdI4NuSPz+5AEsQqAShwCAAjFCgAHyhvP1QAPjiAClBIFERMAC4oS0DNOAAbfJC4TQBrLMSANwKwYCzLAG1S4Cx0Q2yAXQBKNjjohF9-SKDIMOQe1j66EIArNwQAOmr82t1k4LSETC6FiDgAB0SqmuAJvrzC4rLjleAoOBdG5tb2y26ugG58Y1NE+CQ0JgsIEbrUzpxdIZnIYOJ8gA)

Answer (score 1):

enum is a special data structure in TypeScript, personally I can't say that it fully matches `Record<string, string>`.

If you need `Record<string, string>` it is better to use immutable object like this:

```js
const Category = {
  HAZARDOUS: "HAZARDOUS",
  REGULAR: "REGULAR",
} as const
```

I would type it in this way:

```js
enum Category {
  HAZARDOUS = "HAZARDOUS",
  REGULAR = "REGULAR",
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

const func = <Enumerator extends Record<string, string>>(
    enumerator: Enumerator,
    callback: (value: Values<Enumerator>) => string,
) => (Object.values(enumerator) as Array<Values<Enumerator>>).map((value) => callback(value));


func(Category, (value /** Values<typeof Category> */) => 'sdf');
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgF2AJwOYHtkE8oG8CwAUFFABICCAWuQEoAiA8gKoDKUAvFAEQXX3MsuAGiIkaAUQDiTADK0O3CdLk1hRAL5EiCLAAdgUAGpwANmGABnADwAVAHwKbAbQDWwLOgBmUGwF0thADG6CAWCFCeYCCBClbi4BAoiJgixFB2ABSiJFCgkEkImABcUPH5yMnIqTlQgaYmAEZwgS4lGQBupuYlxmaWcQkFmHYAlBwOYcgAliCoqWPsDhkMDQBWwIEIAHSdfRYZeYkVhchjcBZQ5MgVWFa95tZlR5V2o1sQcLoZHV3ACw51EyNZouH59EYjADcASIkWiGXgSDQmCwQigYPM-ygAHILAATTzYqFAA)

I have used type assertion because `Object.values` returns `any[]`

Comment: @adesurirey `Catergory` ?  This is because I have copy/pasted ))

Comment: No about the generic `Enumerator` followed by a `,`. I guess you wanted to write `<Enumerator extends Record<string, string>>` otherwise it's invalid code right ?

Comment: @adesurirey Right